# Can i change the default scope depending on the type of operation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to change my default scope if i'm looking for a single result rather than a collection?

i.e. Model.find(id) vs Model.all

`default_scope lambda { where({:language_id => Language.default_or_first.id}) }`

I really only want to scope my index views this way when i find a whole segment of records.

When i do a Model.find(3) i'd like it to give it to me even if the its not in the default language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unscoped to ignore the default scope.

```
model = Model.unscoped.find(1)
```

will get you your model.

you could also do

```
model = Model.find_by_id!(1)
```

But I really think you should consider not using a default scope at all, It'll likely lead to more headaches further on.

Comment: i ended up finding the unscoped thing already, this fits my needs.